# DbContext and Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I have problem with registration of System.Data.Entity.DbContext in Autofac.
Constructors of my classes are:

```
public DeviceService(IDevice device)
{
   _device = device;
}
public Device(DbContext con)
{
   _localDb = con;
}
```

I tried this :

```
_container = new ContainerBuilder();            
_container.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
_container.RegisterType<Device>().As<IDevice>();
_container.RegisterType<DeviceService>().As<IDeviceService>();
_dependencyContainer = _container.Build();
```

But It didn't work because when I tried resolve `_dependencyContainer.Resolve<IDeviceService>()`, I got this exception:

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException'
>   occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An exception was thrown while activating
>   WpfApplication2.DeviceService -> WpfApplication2.Device ->
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

I can't find solution in Google. What is the solution ?

Comment: Can you show the constructors of the dbcontext?

Comment: Btw, dont you have your own dbcontext?

Comment: You can try to change `_container.RegisterType<DbContext>().As<DbContext>()` to `_container.RegisterType<DbContext>().AsSelf()`

Comment: It is DbContext of EntityFramework, so I can't show you constructor of that DbContext.

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski : this fire the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that injection of System.Data.Entity.DbContext by Autofac is imposible. But you can inject inherited object of that DbContext -> MyContext: DbContext ->

```
_container.RegisterType<MyContext>().AsSelf()
```